# Sort by company not working. Please assist me

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> This is my DB query its not working when i used **sortby company** I have totally 48000 records but its shows only 18000 records. **Sortby status,contact,city all are working fine.** Any help will appreciate

```
public static function retreiveCandidates($status,$alpha=NULL,$dash=NULL,$statusid,$sortby=NULL){
    DB::enableQueryLog();

    $query = DB::table('candidates')->select('candidates.candidateid','candidates.firstname','candidates.lastname','candidates.imageext','candidates.middlename','candidates.personal_email','candidates.city','candidates.mobile','candidates.title_id','candidates.status','candidates.state','candidates.isverified','candidates.candidate_statusid','candidates.sendinvitation','candidates.ismerged','candidates.imagekey','candidates.candidatekey')->where('candidates.status',$status);
    if($alpha!=''){
        $query = $query->where('candidates.firstname', 'like', $alpha . '%');
    }
    if($statusid !=''){
        $query = $query->where('candidates.candidate_statusid',$statusid);
    }
    if($dash !=''){
        $result = $query->orderBy('candidates.created_at', 'desc')->limit(7)->get();
    }

    if($sortby == NULL){
        $query = $query->orderBy('candidates.firstname', 'asc') ;
    }elseif($sortby == 'company'){
        $query = $query->join('candidates_company','candidates_company.candidateid','=','candidates.candidateid')->join('company','company.companyid','=','candidates_company.companyid')->where('candidates_company.status','1')->groupBy('candidates.candidateid')->orderBy('company.company', 'asc')->orderBy('candidates.candidateid', 'asc')  ;
    }elseif($sortby == 'status'){
           $query = $query->join('candidate_status','candidate_status.statusid','=','candidates.candidate_statusid')->orderBy('candidate_status.statusorder', 'asc') ;  
    }elseif($sortby == 'contact'){
        $query = $query->orderBy('candidates.firstname', 'asc');            
    }elseif( $sortby == 'city'){            
        $query = $query->orderBy('candidates.city', 'asc') ;
    }elseif( $sortby == 'state'){           
        $query = $query->orderBy('candidates.state', 'asc') ;
    }

    $result = $query->paginate(PAGELIMIT);
    $d= DB::getQueryLog();
    return $result;     
}
```

> This What I get while printing dbquery

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select count(*) as aggregate from `rsi_candidates` inner join `rsi_candidates_company` on `rsi_candidates_company`.`candidateid` = `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid` inner join `rsi_company` on `rsi_company`.`companyid` = `rsi_candidates_company`.`companyid` where `rsi_candidates`.`status` = ? and `rsi_candidates_company`.`status` = ? group by `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [time] => 1036.83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid`, `rsi_candidates`.`firstname`, `rsi_candidates`.`lastname`, `rsi_candidates`.`imageext`, `rsi_candidates`.`middlename`, `rsi_candidates`.`personal_email`, `rsi_candidates`.`city`, `rsi_candidates`.`mobile`, `rsi_candidates`.`title_id`, `rsi_candidates`.`status`, `rsi_candidates`.`state`, `rsi_candidates`.`isverified`, `rsi_candidates`.`candidate_statusid`, `rsi_candidates`.`sendinvitation`, `rsi_candidates`.`ismerged`, `rsi_candidates`.`imagekey`, `rsi_candidates`.`candidatekey` from `rsi_candidates` inner join `rsi_candidates_company` on `rsi_candidates_company`.`candidateid` = `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid` inner join `rsi_company` on `rsi_company`.`companyid` = `rsi_candidates_company`.`companyid` where `rsi_candidates`.`status` = ? and `rsi_candidates_company`.`status` = ? group by `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid` order by `rsi_company`.`company` asc, `rsi_candidates`.`candidateid` asc limit 10 offset 0
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [time] => 454.11
        )

)
```

Comment: why don't you use eloquent. It will easy for you

Comment: Thanks mate. Can you suggest me any example. It will make me easy to learn

Comment: which laravel version are you using

Comment: currently im usinglaravel 5.3

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommendation for future references, use "===" rather than "==", the second one will yield true in some of the most awkward of cases.

Going into the question, your search has only

> where('candidates_company.status','1')

that might be reducing the scope of your results, without actually seeing the table I couldn't know for sure that's the problem, but I can't really see anything other than that reducing the amount of results being retrieved.

Comment: Ofcourse bro, Now I have a conclusion. Thanks for your comment. where('candidates_company.status','1'). this one is reducing my results

Comment: Great, a pleasure to help. If it isn't a problem might you tag my answer as accepted?

Comment: Sure bro. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Create candidates model

```
php artisan make:model Candidate
```

This will create a model file candidate.php in your app folder . The file looks like

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'candidate'; //give your table name here
}
```

Now you can acces your candidate model in your controller like

```
use App\Candidate;
class CandidateController extends Controller
{
 $candidates= App\Candidate::orderBy('company')->get(); //select by orderby
}
```

Hope this helps